# Querying remote postgres from org

Tags: org-babel, ssh

*this is a bit complicated, please bear with me*

I want to use org-babel to query postgresql, and I can do it for DBs that I can access directly from my localhost:

```
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :cmdline "-h localhost -U postgres -p 5434 -d my_db"
```

I can even probably do that if DB is on a remote ssh machine, by setting ssh tunnel first.

The problem is: in my company (for security reasons) it's made that you have to:

- first ssh to a machine (let's call it `first-lvl-host`)
- and only then access the DB, which is still on a remote host (let's call it `db-lvl-host`)

Another problem is, that `first-lvl-host` does not even have `psql` (command line utility). In order to access it - you have to ssh hop to another machine (let's call it `second-lvl-host`)

Basically I'm expected to do:

```
ssh first-lvl-host ssh second-lvl-host

# and then:
PGPASSWORD=mypass psql -h db-lvl-host -U ag
```

**So, my question is, can I anyhow still do it directly from my org file?**

---

I know I can reduce ssh hops by adding:

```
Host second-lvl-host
  ProxyJump first-lvl-host
```

to my ssh/config, but that still doesn't allow me to access db-machine directly, using local `psql`, and if I can't poke on it with psql, I don't think I can do it with org-babel, or can I?

---

I tried setting a tunnel like this:

```
ssh -L 9999:localhost:9999 first-lvl-host ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N db-lvl-host
```

but that didn't work. I can't ssh to db-lvl-host, even if I do `ssh first-lvl-host ssh second-lvl-host ssh db-lvl-host`. It doesn't work like that. I can't connect to `db-lv-host` via ssh, it reports: "Connection timed out", if I can't ssh to it - means I can't establish a tunnel, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might can try TRAMP multi-hops, Like open the org file on db-lv-host, it has
the SQL babel, then use TRAMP multi-hops to open it, then execute it. It might
will executed on db-lv-host. I have not tested that. But it should work on
theory.

```
#+headers: :cmdline -h localhost -U postgres -w -d my_db -p 5434
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :dir /ssh:user1@host1|/ssh:user2@host2
SELECT * from test
#+end_src
```

If you find it works, can you paste out your steps, I need to know it.

Comment: I think this should work, but it doesn't work for me, because there's one missing piece: the password. I need to find a way to set it and voila

Comment: I've tried setting :dbpassword header as explained in here: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-sql.html, and now getting: `gzip: (stdin): unexpected end of file`

Comment: oh, no... it actually worked, just tried this:

`#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :dir /ssh:uat|ssh:sql-machine: :dbpassword "PASSWORD" :dbhost uat-green-rds-postgres.amazonaws.com :dbuser postgresql :database kafka_connect_postgresql :cmdline "-p 5432"
       select * from bank_transaction limit 1;
   #+end_src`

It didn't work previously because of `\d` command. Although it works locally, you can't expect it to work for remote DBs. Sql statements work fine.

Comment: oh. it seems not related to the command... it has something to do with the number of rows. I guess by default it allows limited number of rows to be transferred. Maybe there's a way to extend that?

Comment: About TRAMP multi-hops SSH connection password, they can be stored in auth-sources, .netrc etc.